# Which converting format of Calibre will keep a MOBI ebook's formatting together?

Tags: calibre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can DRM-free Kindle books still be read on the Kindle app for PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/429349/can-drm-free-kindle-books-still-be-read-on-the-kindle-app-for-pc)

I've got a MOBI/Kindle book and I want to convert it to a format that's easy to markup, make notes etc. but when I try to convert to TXT or PDF the result is awful.  Are any of the other formats in Calibre's conversion options easily opened on any computer; any of the other formats offered by Calibre fare better after a MOBI conversion?

On a side note, are there other programs that will convert a MOBI book better than Calibre?  One that will keep the formatting...

Win 7.
IE 9.

Comment: Umm, not an exact duplicate!  I'm asking about Calibre's ability to keep proper formatting...when converting to PDF.  Please reopen.